# falied to install flask under virutalenv on windows -- [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, windows, flask, virtualenv

I'm using python 2.7 on a windows box.I'm able to install flask using pip install, as you can see below:

[image: cool]
However, after I created a virtualenv, I got below error when trying to do the same thing.

scripts:

```
$pip install virtualenv  
$cd /d d:
$mkdir test
$cd test
$virtualenv  flaskEnv
$cd flaskEnv/Scritps/
$activate
$cd ../../
$pip install flask
```

log file as below:

```
Collecting flask
  Using cached Flask-0.11.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): click>=2.0 in c:\projects\flask-react\flsk\lib\site-packages (from flask)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Werkzeug>=0.7 in c:\projects\flask-react\flsk\lib\site-packages (from flask)
Collecting Jinja2>=2.4 (from flask)
  Using cached Jinja2-2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting itsdangerous>=0.21 (from flask)
Collecting MarkupSafe (from Jinja2>=2.4->flask)
  Using cached MarkupSafe-0.23.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: MarkupSafe
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for MarkupSafe: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for MarkupSafe: finished with status 'error'
  Complete output from command c:\projects\flask-react\flsk\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\admini~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-3ep417\\MarkupSafe\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\tmp8mkr70pip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-2.7
  creating build\lib.win32-2.7\markupsafe
  copying markupsafe\tests.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\markupsafe
  copying markupsafe\_compat.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\markupsafe
  copying markupsafe\_constants.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\markupsafe
  copying markupsafe\_native.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\markupsafe
  copying markupsafe\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\markupsafe
  running egg_info
  writing MarkupSafe.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing top-level names to MarkupSafe.egg-info\top_level.txt
  writing dependency_links to MarkupSafe.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

  reading manifest file 'MarkupSafe.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  writing manifest file 'MarkupSafe.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  copying markupsafe\_speedups.c -> build\lib.win32-2.7\markupsafe
  running build_ext
  building 'markupsafe._speedups' extension
  error: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

  ----------------------------------------
  Running setup.py clean for MarkupSafe
Failed to build MarkupSafe
Installing collected packages: MarkupSafe, Jinja2, itsdangerous, flask
  Running setup.py install for MarkupSafe: started
    Running setup.py install for MarkupSafe: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command c:\projects\flask-react\flsk\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\admini~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-3ep417\\MarkupSafe\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-8v3_ep-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers c:\projects\flask-react\flsk\include\site\python2.7\MarkupSafe:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-2.7
    creating build\lib.win32-2.7\markupsafe
    copying markupsafe\tests.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\markupsafe
    copying markupsafe\_compat.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\markupsafe
    copying markupsafe\_constants.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\markupsafe
    copying markupsafe\_native.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\markupsafe
    copying markupsafe\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\markupsafe
    running egg_info
    writing MarkupSafe.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to MarkupSafe.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to MarkupSafe.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    reading manifest file 'MarkupSafe.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    writing manifest file 'MarkupSafe.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    copying markupsafe\_speedups.c -> build\lib.win32-2.7\markupsafe
    running build_ext
    building 'markupsafe._speedups' extension
    error: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Does the error message mean something to anyone?
thanks

Comment: I think you need  Visual Studio to Build python extensions on windows (https://docs.python.org/3/extending/windows.html).

Comment: thanks. but I'm able to install it globally without using visual studio.

Comment: what really confuses me is why it doesn't work under a virtualenv, while it works perfectly when installing globally?

Answer (score 18):

This issue seems to be related with the setuptools version installed in your virtualenv. Downgrading to an older version fixed it for me.

From your virtualenv:

```
pip install setuptools==21.2.1
pip install flask
```

Comment: This also worked flawlessly for me, this error seems to be some syntax issue way over my head.

Comment: This same fix also worked for me when seeing a similar error while installing Sphinx.

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem yesterday.  I resolved it by downloading the MarkupSafe [wheel](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) and installing with pip.  The problem was way over my head.  Something about compiler flags in order to suppress an error when generating the Speedups file, I think.

1) Download the wheel from the link above.

2) On Windows, open a command window in the same directory as the wheel.

3) run "pip Install "

Comment: Can you please gives some more detail on exactly what steps you took to do that?

Comment: I was trying to install Jupyter Notebook on Windows and MarkupSafe is a dependency. This error regarding MarkupSafe is what popped up when I used `pip` to install Jupyter Notebook.  I searched here for a similar problem and this was the only solution that worked for me.  I had to download the wheel created by Christoph Gohlke, use `pip` to manually install it and I was then able to install Jupyter Notebook successfully.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The setup.py of MarkupSafe is broken for Win7 on my system where there is no C compiler. (I keep a separate VM for VC++ work) I did this to get it working:

```
pip download MarkupSafe 
mkdir temp 
open MarkupSafe-0.23.tar.gz with 7-zip, extract all to temp 
cd temp 
edit setup.py line 119 to read: if 0: #not (is_pypy or is_jython): 
python setup.py install
```

I did not try to debug setup.py to work correctly. I just wanted to try out Flask since it's supposed to be lightweight and easy to learn, and the official docs say it installs on Windows. Maybe I should go back to Perl...

Unlike the other poster, a global pip install of MarkupSafe didn't work for me either.

These links have other views/insights on the problem:
https://github.com/pallets/markupsafe/issues/26
https://github.com/babun/babun/issues/315

Comment: Thankyou, this solved my issue after a bunch of various different attempts - I even tried installing various VC++ versions, but without success.

Answer (score 1):

ok. I figure it out.  I don't think there is anything wrong in the way I install flask, as I already mentioned in my question, I am able to install it globally (without running within a virtualenv). 
the MarkupSafe package has an extension which is implement using c, and I don't have windows sdk installed on my local machine, so when ve_build_ext runs, 
****  it always fail  **

the difference is if not (is_pypy or is_jython) , it gives a warning, which is what i got when installing it globally; it crashes, though, when running under a virtualenv. So I'm pretty sure that hasattr(sys, 'pypy_version_info') return true when running under a virtualenv.

Does anybody have an idea what "hasattr(sys, 'pypy_version_info')" mean??

```
# fail safe compilation shamelessly stolen from the simplejson
# setup.py file.  Original author: Bob Ippolito

is_jython = 'java' in sys.platform
is_pypy = hasattr(sys, 'pypy_version_info')


def run_setup(with_binary):
ext = Extension('markupsafe._speedups', ['markupsafe/_speedups.c'])
ext_modules = [ext] if with_binary else []




def try_building_extension():
    try:
        run_setup(True)
    except BuildFailed:
        LINE = '=' * 74
        BUILD_EXT_WARNING = 'WARNING: The C extension could not be ' \
                            'compiled, speedups are not enabled.'
    echo(LINE)
    echo(BUILD_EXT_WARNING)
    echo('Failure information, if any, is above.')
    echo('Retrying the build without the C extension now.')
    echo()

    run_setup(False)

    echo(LINE)
    echo(BUILD_EXT_WARNING)
    echo('Plain-Python installation succeeded.')
    echo(LINE)
```

if not (is_pypy or is_jython):
    try_building_extension()
else:
    run_setup(False)

Comment: I got a compiled version of markupsafe from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/   and install it locally under virtualenv. After that I am able to install flask in my virtualenv

Comment: I was running under git bash. 
just figured out how to run it in interaction mode

simply type: $python -i

Comment: You should add a link to the wheel repository into this answer and accept it so that others can see what the solution is. And, thank you!

Comment: `sys.pypy_version_info` would be set if you were using PyPy instead of CPython. You'd know if you were using the PyPy interpreter.

Comment: re  martinthenext: I already did

I got a compiled version of markupsafe from lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs and install it locally under virtualenv

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue today and was able to resolve it by manually installing [MarkupSafe](http://www.pocoo.org/projects/markupsafe) from a [wheel](http://pythonwheels.com) file, per Lincoln's suggestion above. You can download the appropriate file [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#markupsafe). There were several available. I don't know what the difference between all of them is, but the only one that would even install on Windows 10 was the one called [MarkupSafe-0.23-cp27-none-win32.whl](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/6kbpejrn/MarkupSafe-0.23-cp27-none-win32.whl). After downloading it, I copied it into the directory I created using virtualenv (not sure if that's necessary but that's what I did) and installed it with pip:

```
C:\flask-test\venv>pip install MarkupSafe-0.23-cp27-none-win32.whl
```

from that directory. After that I went back to the main directory and installed Flask

```
C:\flask-test\venv>cd ..
C:\flask-test>pip install Flask
```

and it worked fine.